# Can Cognito Forms be used without a website?

Tags: cognito-forms

I do not have a website or social media of any sort.  If I create a Cognito Form can my users access the form directly?

Comment: I found the answer at http://help.cognitoapps.com/publishing-a-form  I don't know how I missed it the first time around.

Comment: You should add that as an answer for future readers with the same question. Comments aren't designed to stay around for the long-term.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [link](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/10/style--publish) provided by OP herself:

> **Publishing a form**
>
> You can share your form in three different ways:
>
> •  **Embed in your site** - The best way is to publish your form is to copy the provided Embed code and paste it into your own website. This will embed the form into your website so that users will not have to navigate away from your website in order to fill out the form. An embedded form will allow you to have a form that looks like it belongs on your website.
>
> •  **Share a link** - Another way to publish a form is by providing users a link to the form. This link can be added as a hyperlink in your website or in an email. The link will send the user to a simple page that contains your form for them to fill out.
>
> •  **Social Media** - You can also publish your form by clicking one of the Social Media buttons. Once you select a social media site, a post will be created containing a link to your form.

Ie the answer is "Yes" (eg via email).